# How I'm paying off my student loans

Tags: visual

I've got this QR code that is very important to me, but my [stupid cousin](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/renandstimpy/images/3/31/Sven_Hoek_by_Hamhole.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20131019152312) was carrying it around with him and *dropped and broke it.*
He tried to hide this from me using *tape* and *Elmer's glue* and got it back together, but it doesn't work now.

> Can you help?

[image: broken QR code]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> First, reassemble the QR code. Fortunately there are colored dots at the corners of the pieces to help glue things together (though I suspect that this isn't strictly necessary): [image]
>  You can use the specification of the QR code to help (the corner boxes, for instance.) Now, we simply scan and get:
>
> ```
> :\> Penetrate_Root
> :\> Scan()
>  PayPal...Google Wallet...Apple Passbook...
> :\> Thank_You_For_Your_Donation
> ```
>
> Well, guess I'm broke now. It was fun while it lasted.

Comment: I considered leaving out the dots (and even mirror-imaging some random panels), but didn't want it to be *too* hard.

Comment: A while back I noticed some strange unknown code-like edit to one of the notes on my phone. For a month or two I was wondering how on earth it got there, and whether it was evidence of someone hacking my phone. Then while browsing puzzles, I came across this question today. Turned out, I had scanned this QR code on my phone a long while back, when I first saw this answer, and then left the scanned text in a note on my phone and forgotten that it was there XD